# PHP ORACLE VIEW FROM SELECT

Tags: php, sql, oracle11c, sql-view

Pretendo gerar uma `view` através de um `select` com o código abaixo, mas não funciona, o que pode ser?

`$row[0]` contém `"select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from tabela1"`

```
$select= oci_parse($ora_conexao, 'SELECT * FROM TABELA');
oci_execute($select);
while (($qrow = oci_fetch_row($select)) != false) {
    $arrData[] = $row[0].'<br />';
}
$var = implode('',$arrData);
//--> cria temp view
$view = oci_parse($ora_conexao,"CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW \"TD_ADMIN\".\"view1\" (\"col1\", \"col2\", \"col3\", \"col4\",  \"col5\") AS $var");
oci_execute($view);
```

Comment: Sua descrição. Aparece alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: não, a página fica em branco.

Comment: Coloca isso no inicio da página, `ini_set('display_error', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` veja se aparece o erro.

Comment: continua em branco, aliás, agora dei um echo na conexão ao banco e apresenta OK para a conexão e ao select da variável $var dá o resultado 'select col1... from tabela1'...

Comment: Então está tudo certo, só falta fazer um `fetch()` pegar os resultados, no banco a view aparece criada?

Comment: para testar a criação da view, substituí o valor da variável $var pelo resultado do $select e gerou a view, pelo que o problema deve estar naquele trecho da variável $view... :/
o fetch() encaixa onde?

Comment: descobri o erro... :/
na linha $arrData[] = $row[0].'<br />'; a quebra de linha para o select na criação da view dá erro de sql mas não mostrava na tela... 
ficou assim: $arrData[] = $row[0];
agora sim, tudo resolvido.
obrigado pela ajuda rray.

Comment: Cria uma resposta com esses detalhes :) aaaah sim erro de sintaxe.

Answer (score 1):

descobri o erro, retirando a quebra de linha aqui: $arrData[] = $row[0].'
';

ficou assim e a funcionar:

conexão ao banco:

```
//--> conexao oracle
//--> usuario
$ora_user = "ora_user"; 
//--> senha
$ora_senha = "ora_senha"; 
//--> caminho
$ora_bd = "(DESCRIPTION=
          (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
              (HOST=192.168.1.100)(PORT=1521)
            )
          )
          (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE_TESTE))
     )"; 
//--> monta a conexao
if ($ora_conexao = oci_connect($ora_user,$ora_senha, $ora_bd, 'AL32UTF8')){
    echo 'Conexão bem sucedida';
}else{
    echo 'Conexão falhada';
}
```

cria view de select do banco oracle:

```
$select= oci_parse($ora_conexao, 'SELECT * FROM TABELA');
oci_execute($select);
while (($qrow = oci_fetch_row($select)) != false) {
    $arrData[] = $row[0];
}
$var = implode('',$arrData);
//--> cria temp view
$view = oci_parse($ora_conexao,"CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW \"TD_ADMIN\".\"view1\" (\"col1\", \"col2\", \"col3\", \"col4\",  \"col5\") AS $var");
oci_execute($view);
```